# Evaluating string templates

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a string template as shown below

```
template = '<p class="foo">#{content}</p>'
```

I want to evaluate the template based on current value of the variable called `content`.

```
html = my_eval(template, "Hello World")
```

This is my current approach for this problem:

```
def my_eval template, content
  "\"#{template.gsub('"', '\"')}\""  # gsub to escape the quotes
end
```

Is there a better approach to solving this problem?

## EDIT

I used HTML fragment in the sample code above to demonstrate my scenario. My real scenario has set of XPATH templates in a configuration file. The bind variables in the template are substituted to get a valid XPATH string.

I have thought about using ERB, but decided against as it might be a overkill.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can render a string as if it were an erb template. Seeing that you're using this in a rake task you're better off using Erb.new.

```
template = '<p class="foo"><%=content%></p>'
html = Erb.new(template).result(binding)
```

Using the ActionController methods originally suggested, involves instantiating an ActionController::Base object and sending render or render_to_string.

Comment: I used HTML fragment in the template to demonstrate the scenario. I have bunch of XPATH strings that need substitution. I had thought about using ERB, but I wanted something lightweight.

Comment: I must say this is an intriguing solution. I have to run my code in a rake task. So this solution might need some tweaking.

Comment: If you're talking about a rake task, you're better off using Erb.new instead of ActionController#render. Solution updated to reflect that.

Comment: You beat me to it. I was about to post that code fragment :-)

Comment: Thanks! I found that the second line had to be ERB.new (note the uppercase) for Ruby 1.9.3.

Comment: This is dangerous if there is any possibility that content might (ever) contain ruby code.  Even if it doesn't now, maybe down the road in some other part of your system, some other programmer will append a bit of user-supplied data to the string that is "content".  Using String % as in another answer is safer.

Answer (score 25):

You can do what you want with String's native method '%':

```
> template = "<p class='foo'>%s</p>"
> content = 'value of content'
> output = template % content
> puts output
=> "<p class='foo'>value of content</p>"
```

See http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/String.html#M000770

Comment: Mind_completely_blown.gif

Comment: This is the better answer.

Comment: Might be worth adding that using this method you can have 'named placeholders, i.e. `"Profile: %{name}, %{age}" % { name: 'John', age: 25 }`

Answer (score 4):

I can't say I really recommend either of these approaches. This is what libraries like erb are for, and they've been throughly tested for all the edge cases you haven't thought of yet. And everyone else who has to touch your code will thank you. However, if you really don't want to use an external library, I've included some recommendations.

The `my_eval` method you included didn't work for me. Try something like this instead:

```
template = '<p class="foo">#{content}</p>'

def my_eval( template, content )
  eval %Q{"#{template.gsub(/"/, '\"')}"}
end
```

If you want to generalize this this so you can use templates that have variables other than `content`, you could expand it to something like this:

```
def my_eval( template, locals )
  locals.each_pair{ |var, value| eval "#{var} = #{value.inspect}" }
  eval %Q{"#{template.gsub(/"/, '\"')}"}
end
```

That method would be called like this

```
my_eval( '<p class="foo">#{content}</p>', :content => 'value of content' )
```

But again, I'd advise against rolling your own in this instance.

Answer (score 0):

This is also a nice one:

```
template = "Price of the %s is Rs. %f."
# %s - string, %f - float and %d - integer

p template % ["apple", 70.00]
# prints Price of the apple is Rs. 70.000000.
```

[more here](http://blog.revathskumar.com/2013/01/ruby-multiple-string-substitution-in-string-template.html)

Answer (score 0):

To late but I think a better way is like [ruby-style-guide](https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide#sprintf):

```
template     = '<p class="foo">%<content>s</p>'
content_text = 'Text inside p'
output = format( template , content: content_text )
```